# I am getting the Too many re-renders and going an infinite loop when i am adding the Component CommentCreate in the map function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-error-boundary

PostList Component
when I am adding the createCFommonent then I am getting the too many re-render Error. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './PostList.css'
import CommentCreate from './CommentCreate';

const PostList = () => {
    const [ptitle,setPtitle]=useState({});

    const fetchPost = async ()=> {
        const res=await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/posts')
        setPtitle(res.data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       fetchPost()
    }, [])
    
    const renderedPost = Object.values(ptitle).map((post) => {
      return (
        <div
          className="card"
          style={{ width: "30%", marginBottom: "20px" }}
          key={post.id}
        >
          <div className="card-body">
            <h3>{post.title}</h3>
              <CommentCreate postId={post.id} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Post List</h1>
        {renderedPost}
      </div>
    );
}

export default PostList;
```

**createComment Component**
this is the Component which is giving Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

````
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import './CommentCreate.css'
const CommentCreate = ({postId}) => {
    const [comment, setComment]=useState('')

    const createComment = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post(`http://localhost:9000/post/${postId}/comment`, {
          comment,
        });
    }
    setComment('')
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={comment} onChange={e =>{
            setComment(e.target.value)
        }} placeholder="Create a Comment here" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick={createComment}>
          Comment
        </button>
      </div>
    );

    }

export default CommentCreate;

```
````

Comment: Post your `CommentCreate` component. The problems lie there, I see no issues in `PostList` component.

Comment: hi @PrateekThapa , I have added the createComment Component, can you please tell me what is happening wrong or what is the basic logic for this error, I am struggling here

Answer (score 1):

### PROBLEM

You `createComment` gets updated by parent and `setComment` is called which triggers a re-render again calling `setComment`. Thus an infinite re-render.

### SOLUTION

Place your `setComment` inside the `createComment` function.

```
  const createComment = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        await axios.post(`http://localhost:9000/post/${postId}/comment`, {
          comment,
        });
        
        setComment('')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting state globally `setComment('')`. Consider using `useEffect` if you wanna set state only when component mounts. Use the below snippets:

```
useEffect(() => setComment(''), []);
```

Setting state globally will cause component to re-render and again on re-rendering setComment('') will called, this procedure follows indefinitely and you'll getting the infinte loop error which you are. So my suggestion is never set state without using useEffect or without meeting any specific condition.